# GET Request with react native, populate data to <Text>

Tags: react-native, rest, fetch

I am quite new to React Native, Although, i can send data to Mysql database and all using POST, but i am very new to making GET requests to REST apis.

I have this challenge to make a request to a REST api using some data gotten from a form, and passed thru navigation so I can pass the value to the second form, then onto the API and then use the API to query, return JSON data and display somewhere on the form. Since I am new, I do not know how to go about using GET requests, i just need some explanation here.

My code looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class ShowAccountBalances extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

    
  componentDidMount()
  {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
        const username = navigation.getParam('user','NO-User');
    return fetch('http://192.168.1.100/api/persons/'+username, {
        method : 'GET',
    })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
    
       this.setState({
       dataSource : responseJson.fullname,}, function(){
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Fullname : {this.fullname} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code, the `this.fullName` is taken from nowhere. If you want to get from state, change to `this.state.fullName` and for the callback from GET request, set the state for fullName.

```
this.setState({fullName: responseJson.fullname});
```

and you'll also need to initialize the fullName state like `this.state = {fullName: ''}` in constructor

and you don't have to return the fetch request in componentDidMount, just set the state in its callback, react will do the rest base on your state.